# Function that adds multiple SpriteNodes into array

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have it so that a new SpriteNode is added to the array each time the function runs. It displays the wheat farm the first time the function runs, but each new time only one wheat farm is displayed. I know they are displayed because they are printed to the console. No they are not on top of each other, they are displayed wherever I tap. I believe it is the most recent Sprite added to the screen, because the old one disappears for a bit before I tap for the location of the new one.

```
func buildfarm()  {
        let farm = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "farm.png")
        buildings.append(farm)
        buildings[wheatcounter].position = tappedpos
        buildings[wheatcounter].physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        buildings[wheatcounter].physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        buildings[wheatcounter].physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        buildings[wheatcounter].physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        buildings[wheatcounter].name = "farm"
        self.addChild(buildings[wheatcounter])
        print(buildings)
        wheatcounter = wheatcounter + 1
    }
```

"buildings" is my array
"wheat counter" is how many buildings I have

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is there any other code that affects these nodes ? Also, can you describe a “disappearing” part a bit more. It is not completely clear to me.

Comment: You’ll have to ps the code that puts these sprites on screen.